# ClickFunnels API shows only 10 contacts per page

Tags: json, api

I am using Click Funnels and I wanted to add every new contact directly to the database without any integrations like Zapier or something else.
The problem I have is that while using the ClickFunnels API, I only have access to ten results of the first page.
[https://api.clickfunnels.com/contacts.json?email={{email}}&auth_token={{auth_token}}](https://api.clickfunnels.com/contacts.json?email=%7B%7Bemail%7D%7D&auth_token=%7B%7Bauth_token%7D%7D)

```
{
"data": [
    ...json objects...
],
"jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
},
"links": {
    "self": "https://api.clickfunnels.com/contacts.json?auth_token={{auth_token}}&email={{email}}&page%5Bnumber%5D=1&page%5Bsize%5D=10",
    "first": "https://api.clickfunnels.com/contacts.json?auth_token={{auth_token}}&email={{email}}&page%5Bnumber%5D=1&page%5Bsize%5D=10",
    "prev": null,
    "next": "https://api.clickfunnels.com/contacts.json?auth_token={{auth_token}}&email={{email}}&page%5Bnumber%5D=2&page%5Bsize%5D=10",
    "last": "https://api.clickfunnels.com/contacts.json?auth_token={{auth_token}}&email={{email}}&page%5Bnumber%5D=4&page%5Bsize%5D=10"
}
```

}

I tried to change the page size value, but it doesn't work.
I want to view all the contacts. 
What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

I am having the same problem

Comment: @user3505886 Nope